# Restricting Pages to Admins - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a tutorial on how to restrict pages to admins. In my **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**,  this is how my code looks like

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        // return redirect('/login');
    } else {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->hasRole('manager')) {
            return redirect('admin/home');
        } else {
            return redirect('/home');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

After i login, i am routed to the respective pages but the issue is, i can still route to the admin page even tho i login as a member and not manager. When i place  `localhost/admin/home`, i am still routed to that page although i am not a manager. What am i missing out?

Comment: im posting an answer

Answer (score 1):

You are able to access the manager url after login because your code only redirects each user to their appropriate url's but does'nt do any other check after the users are logged in. You can accomplish this by creating a middleware to check for each user type and redirect them to their appropriate pages and attach this middleware to your desired routes.

In your terminal, run `php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware` to create a `middleware` Note: the `AdminMiddleware` is a name of my choosing and can be changed.

This creates a `middleware` in the `app\Middlewares` directory. edit the contents to look like this..

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(!$user->hasRole('manager'))
        {
            //you can throw a 401 unauthorized error here instead of redirecting back
            return redirect()->back(); //this redirects all non-admins back to their previous url's
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then go to the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file and add the following to the `$routeMiddleware` array.

`'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,`

Now you can attach the `admin` middleware to any route which you would like only `managers` to access.

Comment: "Call to a member function hasRole() on null".

Comment: Seems the Auth is returning null

Comment: I think you are attaching the middleware to a route which guests access

Comment: I would advice you to attach it to routes already using the auth middleware to make sure that the `Auth::user()` always return a user instance